# Which SVG properties can be manipulated using CSS(3)?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I just finished a project that used Raphael.js for svg manipulations. I found that using JS for all style, hover, etc manipulations made the JavaScript bloated and didn't keep the style separated from the code the way I normally prefer.

I then started playing around with pure SVG drawn with JavaScript or just straight SVG elements and how I could manipulate them with pure CSS.

For example:

```
<svg id="circle-svg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
width="400" height="300">
    <circle id="my-circle" cx="100" cy="100" r="50" />
</svg>
```

Can be styled as such:

```
circle {
  fill-opacity: 0.5;
  stroke-width: 4;
  fill: #3080d0;
  stroke: #3080d0;
  transition: fill 0.5s ease;
}
circle:hover{
  stroke-width:6;
  fill: #00f;
}
```

Just to play with... [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2Uyr/)

So far I've found that you can manipulate color, stroke, opacity and even put CSS3 transitions on these properties, but I can't find a definitive list anywhere or a guideline such as "All SVG properties like *this* can be controlled by SVG.

I'm curious because the first project with Raphael was just a POC, but soon we'll be starting a new project and we'll want to clean several aspects of it up (such as mixing the styles in with the JS) and do it in as "modern" a way as possible.

Is there a specific list or rule that defines which SVG properties and/or elements can be controlled by SVG? Also, are there any caveats, such as only svg elements created in a certain way can be styled, whereas others...?

Thanks!

Comment: You can view this webpage, maybe it helps http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/svg-and-css.html

Comment: Worth it a read: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html

Comment: @ZachSaucier It'll probably solve the OP problem, but I think it's better to leave it as a comment. There's no real contribution from me. Just Google and W3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Element attributes are divided in the SVG specification into [CSS properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/propidx.html) and [ordinary attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/attindex.html). Attributes cannot be manipulated by CSS but CSS properties can.

As for CSS3 transitions, it seems that it depends on the [type of the property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-svg) You just need to cross check the CSS properties type with the types that can be animated. For example it seems to me that mask which takes a funciri would be excluded from being animated by CSS3 transitions.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info. Something else I have found is that CSS styles override styles set as an attribute. Who'd a thought that?

Comment: Anyone who read the spec ;-) http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#UsingPresentationAttributes

Comment: [Chart/image version](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1Iuvf3saPCJepVJBDNNDSmSsA0_rwtRYehSmmSSLYFVQ/present#slide=id.g33df2e7c2_15)

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are quite a range of properties that can be styled, the best place to find all your SVG spec queries is at the [W3 website](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/). There's a section in there on styling.

As far as I'm aware any SVG you add to the DOM should be styleable via CSS. You have to remember that CSS is added to the DOM, and treated like normal DOM. That is why it's slower than canvas because the browser has to parse the SVG you're adding, but you get the benefits of regular DOM like CSS and using jQuery selectors for example.